# Controller and service with the first two letters uppercase

Tags: grails

I have a controller named `EQuestionController` and a service named `EQuestionService` in Grails 2.5.3.

When I call the controller I need to do it as `/EQuestion` when I was expecting to call it as `/eQuestion`, but in this case a 404 error comes up.

When I inject the service in a controller I need to do it as `def EQuestion` when I was expecting to inject it as `def eQuestion`, but in this case it is `null`.

Isn't it right to name a controller or a service with the first two letters uppercase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this naming behavior is defined in the java bean spec (http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec)

> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower case. However to support the occasional use of all
>   upper-case names, we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone.
>   So for example,

```
“FooBah” becomes “fooBah”  
“Z” becomes “z”
“URL” becomes “URL”
```

So, the bean of `EQuestionService` becomes `EQuestionService`

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for